# Random php session causes different value when i use # this in img tag like <img src="#">

Tags: php, html, session

In my project I have a text editor and has a Image upload specification it will upload the picture according to $_SESSION['imageID'] and $_SESSION['userID'] and when it is done it will show that picture in my editor iframe.

Note: For uploading pictures I used popup window and another php file like uploader.php.

Every ting is working well until I try the add preview section for my text editor. Then one by one I checked my preview codes and I found the problem. It's just #, in img tag src="#". It's causes different value $_SESSION['imageID'] in my uploader.php than texteditor.php.

Simply which causes this problem codes like this:

texteditor.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'function.php';
$_SESSION['imageID']=rast(); 
echo "Image ID :".$_SESSION['imageID'];?>
<img class="preview_image" src="#"/>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "Image ID :".$_SESSION['imageID'];
?>
```

For Example output like this:

From texteditor.php

```
Image ID :vKF8Ro6hI2VpyYX
```

From upload.php

```
Image ID :O5cg7Ro0vo882FP
```

Note:rast(); gives me random 15 charters from a to z, A to Z, 0 to 9 and date.

Question is Why my $_SESSION['imageID'] is causes different value in my uploader.php than texteditor.php when I use "#" this in img tag like < img src="#"/> that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to start the session like so: `session_start();`

Comment: Still same just I forget the add up here

Comment: Why does this row `php $_SESSION['imageID']=rast(); ` start with `php`? Btw, does texteditor.php get reloaded during this process?

Comment: Sorry bad editing :(. Still it's same

Comment: I just used substr(str_shuffle("a to z, A to Z, 0 to 9 to 9 and date"), 0, "15"); in my rast(); function  and I tried rand(); , it's causes same problem.

Comment: Just problem is when I use # this in img tag like <img src="#">. I just want to know why it's happening. If i leave like <img src=""> or <img src="asdf.jpg.png...."> my codes are working well.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by writing `<img src="#"/>`?

Comment: that code is my preview side code and i want the change src after with js i don't now why i used there # maybe i mixed with <a href="#">.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of fiddling around i finally figured it out.

When you set the image's source to be `#`, the browser converts that to `http://www.somesite.com/texteditor.php#`

- This is so that if you wrote `#content`, the browser would scroll to the element with the id `content`

After the browser has converted the `src` tag, it tries to load the page `http://www.somesite.com/texteditor.php#`, because it thinks it will receive an image.

Therefore your browser loads the page twice, and your `rast()` function is called twice.